# implement login authentication using zend model and controller

Tags: php, extjs, zend-db, zend-framework2

I am using Zend 2.0 and I have never used EXTJS in combination with Zend.

Here is my extjs code in view/login/index.phtml:

```
<?php $this->inlineScript()->captureStart() ?>
var LoginWindow
Ext.onReady(function() {

    LoginWindow = new Ext.create('Ext.window.Window',{
        title: 'Login',
        closable: false,
        draggable: false,
        resizable: false,
        width: 370,
        items: [
            Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
                id: 'LoginForm',

                bodyPadding: 5,
                width: 350, 

                url: '/',
                layout: 'anchor',
                defaults: {
                    anchor: '100%'
                },

                // The fields
                defaultType: 'textfield',
                items: [{
                    fieldLabel: 'Username',
                    name: 'user',
                    allowBlank: false
                },{
                    fieldLabel: 'Password',
                    inputType: 'password',
                    name: 'pw',
                    allowBlank: false
                }],

                // Reset and Submit buttons
                buttons: [{
                    text: 'Reset',
                    handler: function() {
                        this.up('form').getForm().reset();
                    }
                },
                {
                    text: 'Submit',
                    formBind: true,
                    disabled: true,
                    handler: function() {
                        var form = this.up('form').getForm();

                    }
                }]
            })
        ]
    });
    Ext.getBody().mask()

    LoginWindow.show()  

});

<?php $this->inlineScript()->captureEnd() ?>
```

Now I am not sure how to send the username/password to LoginController.php and use the model to authenticate username/password from the database table.

Any example or possible solution would really help.

Comment: you should submit your form to your endpoint. getForm() is useles without doing something with the values.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please do not consider the following as a ready to use solution. I also added some more parts that you will find useful when you start managing your logins. The main part for you should be the routing an the controller. I also spared the view content, except the ExtJS part of it. Anyway, I hope this helps you.

First there where some issues within your form. Try the following one

```
var loginWindow;
Ext.onReady(function() {

    loginWindow = new Ext.create('Ext.window.Window',{
        title: 'Login',
        closable: false,
        draggable: false,
        resizable: false,
        width: 370,
        modal: true,
        items: [
            Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
                id: 'LoginForm',
                bodyPadding: 5,
                width: 350, 
                layout: 'anchor',
                defaults: {
                    anchor: '100%'
                },
                defaultType: 'textfield',
                items: [{
                    fieldLabel: 'Username',
                    name: 'user',
                    allowBlank: false
                },{
                    fieldLabel: 'Password',
                    inputType: 'password',
                    name: 'pw',
                    allowBlank: false
                }],

                url: 'Login/Auth', // first one should be your controller, second one the controller action (this one need to accept post)
                buttons: [
                    {
                        text: 'Reset',
                        handler: function() {
                            this.up('form').getForm().reset();
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'Submit',
                        formBind: true,
                        disabled: true,
                        handler: function() {
                            var form = this.up('form').getForm();
                            if (form.isValid()) {
                                form.submit({
                                    success: function(form, action) {
                                       Ext.Msg.alert('Success', 'Authenticated!');
                                    },
                                    failure: function(form, action) {
                                        Ext.Msg.alert('Failed', 'Authentication Failed');
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            })
        ]
    }).show();
    // Ext.getBody().mask(); <- modal property does the same
});
```

Now to ZF2

**The Routing**

Each page of the application is known as an action and actions are grouped into controllers within modules. Hence, you would generally group related actions into a controller.

The mapping of a URL to a particular action is done using routes that are defined in the module’s module.config.php file. You should add a route for the Login actions. This is the updated module config file with the new code within commentation blocks.

```
<?php
return array(
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Login\Controller\Login' => 'Login\Controller\LoginController',
        ),
    ),

    // The following section is new and should be added to your file
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'login' => array(
                'type'    => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/login[/:action][/:username][/:password]',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'username' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'password' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Login\Controller\Login',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),

    'view_manager' => array(
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            'login' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),
);
```

The name of the route is ‘login’ and has a type of ‘segment’. The segment route allows you to specify placeholders in the URL pattern (route) that will be mapped to named parameters in the matched route. In this case, the route is **/login[/:action][/:id]** which will match any URL that starts with /login. The next segment will be an optional action name, and then finally the next segment will be mapped to an optional id. The square brackets indicate that a segment is optional. The constraints section allows you to ensure that the characters within a segment are as expected, so you have limited actions to starting with a letter and then subsequent characters only being alphanumeric, underscore or hyphen.

**The controller**

Now you need to set up the controller. The controller is a class that is generally called {Controller name}Controller. Note that {Controller name} must start with a capital letter. This class lives in a file called {Controller name}Controller.php within the Controller directory for the module. In your case that would be something like module/Login/src/Login/Controller. Each action is a public method within the controller class that is named {action name}Action. In your case {action name} should start with a lower case letter.

```
<?php
namespace Login\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class LoginController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function authenticateAction($username, $password)
    {
        $params = array('driver' => 'driver',
                        'dbname' => 'name');

        $db = new DbAdapter($params);

        use Zend\Authentication\Adapter\DbTable as AuthAdapter;
        // Oversimplified example without even hashing the password
        $adapter = new AuthAdapter($db,
                                   'Logins',
                                   'username',
                                   'password'
                                   );

        // get select object (by reference)
        $this->_adapter->setIdentity($username);
        $this->_adapter->setCredential($password);

        $result = $adapter->authenticate();

        if($result->isValid()) {
            // authenticated
        }
    }

    protected $loginTable;
    public function getLoginTable()
    {
        if (!$this->loginTable) {
            $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
            $this->loginTable = $sm->get('Login\Model\LoginTable');
        }
        return $this->loginTable;
    }
}
```

**The view script**

These files will be executed by the DefaultViewStrategy and will be passed any variables or view models that are returned from the controller action method. These view scripts are stored in our module’s views directory within a directory named after the controller. Create these four empty files now:

*module/Login/view/login/login/authenticate.phtml`*

**The Model**

Create a file called *Login.php* under *module/Login/src/Login/Model*:

```
<?php
namespace Login\Model;

class Login
{
    public $id;
    public $username;
    public $password;

    public function exchangeArray($data)
    {
        $this->id     = (isset($data['id'])) ? $data['id'] : null;
        $this->username = (isset($data['username'])) ? $data['username'] : null;
        $this->password  = (isset($data['password'])) ? $data['password'] : null;
    }
}
```

Create your *LoginTable.php* file in *module/Login/src/Login/Model* directory like this:

```
<?php
namespace Login\Model;

use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;

class LoginTable
{
    protected $tableGateway;

    public function __construct(TableGateway $tableGateway)
    {
        $this->tableGateway = $tableGateway;
    }

    public function fetchAll()
    {
        $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->select();
        return $resultSet;
    }

    public function getLogin($id)
    {
        $id  = (int) $id;
        $rowset = $this->tableGateway->select(array('id' => $id));
        $row = $rowset->current();
        if (!$row) {
            throw new \Exception("Could not find row $id");
        }
        return $row;
    }

    public function saveLogin(Login $login)
    {
        $data = array(
            'username' => $login->password,
            'password'  => $login->username,
        );

        $id = (int)$login->id;
        if ($id == 0) {
            $this->tableGateway->insert($data);
        } else {
            if ($this->getLogin($id)) {
                $this->tableGateway->update($data, array('id' => $id));
            } else {
                throw new \Exception('Form id does not exist');
            }
        }
    }

    public function deleteLogin($id)
    {
        $this->tableGateway->delete(array('id' => $id));
    }
}
```

**Use ServiceManager to configure the table gateway and inject into the LoginTable**

Add this method to the bottom of the *Module.php* file in *module/Login*.

```
<?php
namespace Login;

// Add these import statements:
use Login\Model\Login;
use Login\Model\LoginTable;
use Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet;
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;

class Module
{
    // getAutoloaderConfig() and getConfig() methods here

    // Add this method:
    public function getServiceConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'factories' => array(
                'Login\Model\LoginTable' =>  function($sm) {
                    $tableGateway = $sm->get('LoginTableGateway');
                    $table = new LoginTable($tableGateway);
                    return $table;
                },
                'LoginTableGateway' => function ($sm) {
                    $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                    $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
                    $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Login());
                    return new TableGateway('login', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
                },
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

Finally, you need to configure the ServiceManager so that it knows how to get a *Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter*. 
Modify *config/autoload/global.php* with following code

```
<?php
return array(
    'db' => array(
        'driver'         => 'Pdo',
        'dsn'            => 'mysql:dbname=zf2tutorial;host=localhost',
        'driver_options' => array(
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
        ),
    ),
    'service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter'
                    => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory',
        ),
    ),
);
```

You should put your database credentials in *config/autoload/local.php*

```
<?php
return array(
    'db' => array(
        'username' => 'YOUR USERNAME HERE',
        'password' => 'YOUR PASSWORD HERE',
    ),
);
```

You may also find the following code snippets useful (take a look at *tests* and *demos*):

https://github.com/zendframework/zf2

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems in one question. Start by studying Zend_Auth for how to verify a password, Zend_Controller on how to retrieve parameters from a request, Zend_Form on how to send those parameters, Zend_View on how to relate some js with the rest of your app.

In short, the password and username are sent through a form and your application gets them through a getParams method from the Request object.

I dont have too many links to send you to, the docs for ZF2 are quite a few for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Its not very clear what you're asking so I'm going to write a generic answer, it will not be specific to zend framework cause I don't know the zend framework. But the following points are applicable to any technology to use for authentication.

1. You will have to do a normal form POST to the server. You can
   achieve that in extjs by either sending a AJAX post using

   ```
   form.submit(options)
   ```

   or doing a normal HTML submit by setting `standardSubmit : true` on
   the form. The documentation for both are [here](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel-method-submit) & [here](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic-cfg-standardSubmit). As
   quoted in the documentation of `Ext.form.Panel`

   > Although not listed as configuration options of FormPanel, the
   >   FormPanel class accepts all of the config options supported by the
   >   Ext.form.Basic class, and will pass them along to the internal
   >   BasicForm when it is created.
2. Passwords should be stored in the DB in an encrypted format for
   security reasons. Also, for the same security reasons, passwords
   should not be compared in your code after decrypting the stored
   password from the DB. Hence a standard query for authentication
   would be like

   ```
   select * from users where username='username' and password='password'
   ```

   The password passed to the above query should be encrypted too. The
   results of the above query should determine whether the user has
   been successfully authenticated. If the query returns 0 results,
   then the authentication has failed.  Also, the advantage of using
   the above style is that you have a user object that you can
   associate with a session without having to make an extra query.

Hence the follow should go something like this :

1. POST
2. Controller catches request
3. Retrieves username password
4. Passes to Service
5. Service calls the encryptor and gets the encrypted password
6. Passes username and encrypted password to DAO
7. DAO runs the query and returns the results Service
8. Service decides if user authenticated and passes decision to Controller
9. Controller sends appropriate response to user

I Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

The [ZfcUser](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser) module has a working implementation of login-authentication. It's part of [ZF-Commons](https://github.com/ZF-Commons) group of modules so you can also bet on it being actively maintained.

Great for reference or just to use outright.